# Max/Min of Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be Independent random variables following the Bernoulli law with parameter $p$, what is the law of $\min(X,Y)$ and $\max(X,Y)$, I said that $P(\min(X,Y)) = 1-p^2$ and $P(\max(X,Y))=p^2$ is this right?

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you asked many questions that were answered in the comments. Here at MSE it is preferred that questions get answered with actual answers (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4426/405572); if you'd be so kind as to write up what you learned from the comments as answers to your own questions, that would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=min(X,Y)$. Then, $Z = 0$ if $X=0, Y=0$ or $X=0,Y=1$, or $X=1, Y=0$.

Thus, $P(Z = 0) = (1-p)^2 + 2p(1-p) = 1-p^2$, and also $P(Z=1) = p^2$.

Similarly for $P(max(X,Y)).$

Comment: but if i wrote in the exam only $P(min(X,Y)=0) = 1-p^2$ and $P(max(X,Y)=1) = 1- P(min(X,Y)=0) = p^2$ would that still remain valid because we are in a bernoulli world where $X(\Omega) = \{0,1\}$?

Comment: No, that's not correct, because $P(max(X,Y) = 1) = P(X=0, Y=1) + P(X=1, Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1) = 2 p(1-p)+p^2 = 2p - p^2$ Then, $P(max(X,Y)=0) = 1-2p +p^2.$

Comment: so the law of max doesnt follow a bernoulli distribution?

Comment: It does, but the probability masses, for $Z=0$ and $Z=1$, where $Z=max(X,Y)$  are as indicated in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\min (X, Y)$ takes two values $0$ and $1$ then it follows the Bernoulli law with the parameter : 
   $$q = P(\min(X, Y) = 1) = P(X = 1, Y = 1) = P(X = 1) P(Y = 1) = p^2$$
   because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

   $\max (X, Y)$ takes two values $0$ and $1$ then it follows the Bernoulli law with the parameter : 
   $$r = P(\max(X, Y) = 1) = 1 - P(\max(X, Y) = 0) = 1 - P(X = 0, Y = 0) = 1 - P(X = 0) P(Y = 0) = 1 - p^2$$
   because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.